# Servlet gets invoked twice

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic, lifecycle, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper with its integrated weblogic server. I have a cart application. When a user clicks on a particular alphabet, "AlphabetServlet" is triggered and accesses and transfers the data to a view(jsp). Against each product row, there is a "Add to Cart" button which is supposed to transfer the data to a "CartServlet". But when I click "Add to cart" button, the data goes to the "CartServlet", and then the "AlphabetServlet" also gets invoked. I don't understand why this AlphabetServlet is invoked twice and how do I prevent this. Is there any setting in weblogic that I need to take care of? The issue is browser neutral.

Comment: It probably has to do with the code of the cart servlet. Things don't happen magically. My guess is simply that the cart servlet redirects to the alphabet servlet. But it's impossible to confirm without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `CartServlet` is redirecting the request to `AlphabetServlet`. Check your CartServlet code.

Regards,